# Google cloud function - Unable to deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, cloud, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I have lots of cloud function deployed and working fine. (I am the project owner)
Now I am not able to deploy any function and keep on getting this error -

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))
If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback
To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
```

Comment: Most likely you have a temporary Internet connection problem. Wait and try again later.

Comment: Did you report the issue to Google as the error message advised?